# How to distribute objects around spiral in Adobe Illustartor

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo, path

I'm trying to distribute the leaf objects (perpendicularly) around spiral, so the leaf on the outside is the bigest and the smallest is on the inside. I'm replacing old logo with new one. It should look a bit like letter C at the end.

Please see image attached (old one on the left)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea that may work for you... Use a transform effect on a single leaf. You can set a number of copies on the effect and the transformations are cumulative, so you can scale, move and rotate to get the spiral effect.

1. Draw a single leaf (draw it vertically, i.e. not rotated).
2. With the single leaf selected go to *Effect → Distort & Transform → Transform...*
3. Set the scale, move and rotation (also set the rotation origin to the bottom left) to something similar to the following:

[image]

Tip: If you need your transform origin to be outside of the original object you can group the original object with another larger transparent object.

Also uncheck "Scale Strokes & Effects" if you want to keep your strokes and effects uniform.

Even if you can't get the exact placement you want with the effect, you can get it close, expand the effect (*Object → Expand Appearance*) and manually adjust each object from there.

Answer (score 3):

You could use use "step and repeat" OR

1. Create first and last leaf
2. go to "object>blend>blend options" chose  "specified steps" and enter the amount of leafs you want minus 2 (the ones you already have)
3. press alt+ctrl+b (or alt+cmd+b) and create the blend.
4. select spiral and the blending, go again to "object>blend>blend options" and choose "replace spine".